# Compute a discrete Fourier Transform matrix in Julia?

Tags: julia, fft

In Julia, I would like to randomly generate a **discrete fourier transform** matrix of size n by n. I am currently not sure how to how to do such. Does anyone perhaps know a way to do this in Julia?

Comment: You can use FFTW.jl.

Answer (score 2):

As [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74579594/compute-a-discrete-fourier-transform-matrix-in-julia#comment131645619_74579594) in the comments, you can use the `FFTW.jl` package for this purpose:

```
julia> using FFTW

julia> n = 5;

julia> rnd = rand(1:100, n, n);

julia> fft(rnd)
5×5 Matrix{ComplexF64}:
   1216.0+0.0im      65.8754+10.3181im   106.125+119.409im   106.125-119.409im  65.8754-10.3181im
  160.529-95.3957im  177.376-31.8946im  -28.6976+150.325im   52.8237+139.038im  82.2517-165.542im
 -91.0288-22.1566im  136.676+28.1im     -42.8763-97.2573im  -97.7517+4.15021im  8.19756-13.5548im
 -91.0288+22.1566im  8.19756+13.5548im  -97.7517-4.15021im  -42.8763+97.2573im  136.676-28.1im
  160.529+95.3957im  82.2517+165.542im   52.8237-139.038im  -28.6976-150.325im  177.376+31.8946im
```

And for a `Real` datatype, you can use the `rfft` function:

```
julia> let n = 5
           rnd = rand(n, n)
           rfft(rnd)
       end
3×5 Matrix{ComplexF64}:
    10.54+0.0im         1.15104+0.522166im  -0.449373-0.686863im  -0.449373+0.686863im    1.15104-0.522166im
  -1.2319+0.3485im    -0.622914-0.649385im    1.39743-0.733653im    1.66696+0.694317im   -1.59092-0.578805im
 0.501205+0.962713im   0.056338-0.207403im  0.0156042-0.181913im   -1.87067-1.66951im   -0.672603-0.969665im
```

It might rise the question that why the result is a 3x5 matrix:
According to the official doc about the `rfft` function:

> *"Multidimensional FFT of a real array `A`, exploiting the fact that the transform has conjugate symmetry in order to save roughly half the computational time and storage costs compared with fft. If `A` has size (n_1, ..., n_d), the result has size (div(n_1,2)+1, ..., n_d)."*

It's also possible to first create a random nxn matrix with the `eltype` of `ComplexF64` and perform the `fft` on it; For this create the `rnd` variable like `rand(ComplexF64, n, n)` in the above `let` block, and replace the `rfft` with `fft` function.